# Cannot invoke method multiply() on null object

Tags: android-studio, gradle, react-native

I'm trying to generate split apk in react-native and getting this error after setting these two properties:
`def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true`
`def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true`
This is the error I'm getting:

> Cannot invoke method multiply() on null object
>   Open File

On clicking the open file, it is pointing me to this code:

```java
 if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
        output.versionCodeOverride =
             versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
 }
```

My configurations are like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId PACKAGE_NAME
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName MY_VERSION_HERE
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3, "x85_64":4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me with this or at least give me a clue why this should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I ended creating another project, installing all the repository and it worked.
Still, don't know why it was happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you should change "x85_64" -> "x86_64" in the applicationVariants.all setting

Answer (score 0):

Debuging here I added a line:

```
 println abi
```

before the `output.versionCodeOverride` line and saw the abi needed. Then, added the abi on line `def versionCodes`. It ends like:

```
def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3, "x86_64":4]
```